# Kernel and image of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator then $ker(T) \subseteq Im(T)$ if and only if $\forall v \in V$, if $ \ T(v) \in Ker(T)$ then $v \in Ker(T)$

I was trying this for the first part, let $v \in V$ such that $T(v) \in Ker(T) \subseteq Im(T)$ then $\exists w \in V$ such that $T(w) = T(v)$ as T is linear $T(w-v) =T(w)-T(v)=0$ then $w-v \in Ker(T)$ from here I don't know how to conclude that $v \in Ker(T)$

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I add some more context, I don't know how to continue the proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $T$ be the operator represented by the matrix: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\ 1&0\end{array}\right)$$

Then $\ker(T)=\left<\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 1\end{array}\right)\right>={\rm Im}(T)$.

However $T\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 1\end{array}\right)\in \ker(T)$, but $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right)\notin \ker(T)$.

Now let $T$ be the operator represented by the matrix: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)$$

Then $T^2=T$, so $T^2v=0 \implies Tv=0$.  That is $Tv\in\ker(T)\implies v\in \ker(T)$.

However $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right)\in \ker(T)$, but $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right)\notin {\rm Im}(T)$.

Thus neither implication is true.